# shell script - looping line by line - space vs line brake

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have very simple script:

```
$ cat $$.sh
#!/bin/sh -x

VAR="one two
three four"

for i in $VAR ; do
    echo $i
done
$
```

run output:

```
$ sh -x $$.sh
+ VAR='one two
three four'
+ for i in '$VAR'
+ echo one
one
+ for i in '$VAR'
+ echo two
two
+ for i in '$VAR'
+ echo three
three
+ for i in '$VAR'
+ echo four
four
$
```

seems like it's looking for a space and I need for it to look for line break instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're reading multiple lines, line-by-line, then a `while read` loop is a common way to do this:

```
VAR="one two
three four"

while IFS='' read -r i ; do
    echo "$i"
done <<< "$VAR"
```

This produces:

```
one two
three four
```

Note in this example, the while loop is taking input from the `$VAR` variable using a [bash here-string redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings).  But this could just as easily be a redirection from a file or pipe.

Comment: Definitely the best-practice approach. Described in detail in BashFAQ #1: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: ...that said, you should probably use `read -r` here (to read backslash-escape sequences literally rather than interpreting them), and clear `IFS` if the user doesn't explicitly want newlines trimmed... so: `while IFS= read -r i; do`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, that's more robust

Answer (score 2):

The shell would perform word splitting on space and newline by default.  Set `IFS` to a newline instead.  Moreover, if you are using `for` then it's better to turn off globbing (as suggested by [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)):

```
set -o noglob

VAR="one two
three four"

IFS=$'\n'
for i in $VAR ; do
    echo $i
done
```

This would produce:

```
one two
three four
```

Comment: Need to turn off glob expansion for this to be reliable -- see what happens when you have a line containing only `*`, or a line containing `[foo]` anywhere in its text with a shell that happens to have the `nullglob` option enabled.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy One doesn't need to see that, does one?  It'd produce the list of files in the current directory `:)`

Comment: Exactly. Probably not what the user is looking for. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've added that to the answer.  Thanks for reminding :)